# How do I target a DOM element with closest and find and have it as a jQuery dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

This is my code:

```
$(function(){
    $('.pop').dialog({
        autoOpen: false
    });

   $('.show_pop').click(function(){  
       $(this).closest('.parent').find('.pop').dialog('open');
   }); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0v62hL7p/4/

I need to target only one .pop and open the dialog.

What am I missing in my code? Thanks! I'm still new so please bear with me...

Comment: Reliable way: http://jsfiddle.net/0v62hL7p/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery UI rebuild HTML markup for UI dialog, you could use this way instead, targeting specific dialog depending index:

```
$('.show_pop').click(function () {
    $('.pop').eq($(this).index('.show_pop')).dialog('open');
});
```

### -DEMO jsFiddle-

Answer (score 1):

Every dialog needs to be uniquely identifiable so use id instead of class for you dialog.
In your case if you want 2 dialogs give them 2 separate ids and initialize them separately.
Follow code in the manual.
http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated